# How to pass text with # in the beginning to a macro (minted)?

Tags: macros, minted, code

I created a command to input code in my document with minted.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\inlinecode}[2][text]{%
  \mintinline{#1}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}%
  something \inlinecode{somecode} important
  something \inlinecode{#pragma} important
  something \mintinline{text}{#pragma} important
\end{document}
```

The problem is the second line in the document. The output is `##pragma` instead of `#pragma`.
The other two commands produce the expected output. So how do I pass the text with the `#` in the beginning to the command in order to get the correct output?

Comment: `\newcommand{\inlinecode}[1][text]{\mintinline{#1}}` should work.

Comment: `\inlinecode{\#pragma}` should work or `\inlinecode{\# pragma}`. To test I apparently need to get at least the `pygmentize` package and I'm not going to do that as in my general work I don't need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you define

```latex
\newcommand{\inlinecode}[2][text]{%
  \mintinline{#1}{#2}%
}
```

then upon calling `\inlinecode{...}`, the argument is tokenized *before* `\mintinline` can do the changes to the standard interpretations of special characters it needs (it is a special verbatim mode).

Just change the definition into

```latex
\newcommand{\inlinecode}[1][text]{%
  \mintinline{#1}%
}
```

Now `\mintinline` can do its job and absorb itself the argument still not tokenized.

Note that you can also use

```latex
\inlinecode|text|
```

with this definition.

Full example

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\inlinecode}[1][text]{%
  \mintinline{#1}%
}

\begin{document}%
  text \inlinecode{somecode} text
  text \inlinecode{#pragma} text
  text \mintinline{text}{#pragma} text
\end{document}
```

[image]

What happens? When TeX sees (the new) `\inlinecode` it scans ahead to see whether `[` is next. If no `[` is found, then `\mintinline{text}` replaces `\inlinecode`, so the next step will be processing

```latex
\mintinline{text}{#pragma}
```

With a call such as `\inlinecode[cpp]{#pragma}`, the `[` is scanned, so the definition of the macro makes the replacement into `\mintinline{cpp}`; eventually

```latex
\mintinline{cpp}{#pragma}
```

will be processed.

Comment: Sorry, I think I created some confusion with the "text"s. I changed the question. The first argument is actually the language. So for example with \mintinline{cpp}{#pragma}, minted uses the C++ lexer. With the command definition above, there is no way to change the language, correct?

Comment: @Fabian `\inlinecode[cpp]{#pragma}`

Comment: Thank you! It works, but why? Isn't the number, in this case [1], the number of arguments? So the new definition has only 1. Therefore, I am bit confused, why it is ok to just have this one argument? If I use \inlinecode{#pragma}, I thought that #1 is now #pragma, and that the default value for #1, which is "text", should be overwritten. But I just tried it, and it is not.
Same for \inlinecode[cpp]{#pragma}. Why can I use \inlinecode with two arguments, if it is defined with only one?

Comment: @Fabian Due to the way TeX arguments work, here `\mintedinline` will 'keep looking' for it's second argument once it is inserted on expansion of `\inlinecode`. There is no real sense of a command strictly taking only the given number of arguments: TeX is not like functional programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

In general:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\inline}[1]{#1}
\begin{document}
\inline{\#pragma} \inline{magpie}
\end{document}
```

`#` is one of LaTeX's seven symbols and has a special significance. The others are: $ % & _ { }. To print them precede them with a backslash as I did above.

Comment: I get the complete output "\#pragma" in this case.

Comment: @Fabian Odd, I get `#pragma`. I have never been able to post the results of processing a LaTeX document to SE; it just doesn't like me for this. Processing my MWE I get `#pragma magpie`.

Comment: You are totally right. With your code you get only one #. If I pass the \# to \mintinline, I get the \#